Tailwind color styles not applying
I'm  trying to get Tailwind set up for a simple static web page. However, changes in color is not being applied. Interestingly, other styling changes such as enlarging and underlining text is appearing on the webpage, which leads me to believe that tailwind is set up correctly.
Here is my html:
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link href="./output.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <title>Test Page</title>
</head>
    <body>
        <div class="bg-black">
            <h1 class="text-3xl underline text-white">Color Testing</h1>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>


As you can see from the image below, my text is being styled but colors aren't being applied.

I have even gone as far as explicitly defining colors in my tailwind.config.js file here:
/** @type {import('tailwindcss').Config} */

const colors = require('tailwindcss/colors')

module.exports = {
  content: [
    "./src/**/*.{html,js}",
           ],
  theme: {
    extend: {},
    colors: {
      transparent: 'transparent',
      current: 'currentColor',
      black: colors.black,
      white: colors.white,
      slate: colors.slate,
  },
  plugins: [],
}


Even more interestingly, when I apply basic inline css styling, such as style="color:red;", it works?!
There may be some stupidly easy solution to my issue here, so please keep in mind I'm extremely new to the world of the web.

h1.text-white {
color:white !important;
}
If you can update the class for the header to force it to be white with !important it might just start working.

Even without using !important, standard inline css is being applied as stated in the question. My trouble is getting tailwind to apply those styles instead. Is there somewhere in my tailwind config I could apply the !important tag?

Does tailwind allow you to make custom ccs classes such as the one you called "text-white", unless that is a built in one from tailwind?  If so search the css file for that and update the class because most likely you have another class its inhereting from perhaps even the body tag, so to over ride that you must use !important, and so either you need to make the text-white class like i showed, or you need to update the existing one to be !important

Consider checking you've run a Tailwind compilation since you made changes. Also check you are not requesting a cached version of output.css – open your browser's developer tools, check the Disable Cache option is enabled and then refresh webpage.

Clearing cache didn't seem to do anything. I've sifted through my output.css file, and don't seem to find anything pointing to a potential error. That said, I'm not sure. You can find the project here: link

I've cloned the project and tailwind works fine after add the missing } at the end of the tailwind.config.js. Also, looking at your output.css it is missing the classes you have used in html. There is something wrong with the Tailwind compilation.
